# How to find the ILE C function corresponding to CHGJOB INQMSGRPY(*DFT) on IBM i-series (AS/400)

Tags: c, command, ibm-midrange

I know that lots of CL commands are available in C ILE but it's often very hard to find the C function name corresponding to the CL command.

Do you know a website who reference all these ILE C function ?
Do you know the ILE C function corresponding to the CL command :
CHGJOB INQMSGRPY(*DFT)

Of course I've tried to search on IBM public boulder site ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience calling APIs from C, but I think you're looking for the QWTCHGJB API.

[Here's IBM's QWTCHGJB API documentation for V5R4](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/qwtchgjb.htm).

[Here's a code example that demonstrates a call to this API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzam3/rzam3kickoff.htm).

[You can use the API finder to search for this sort of info.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apifinder/finder.htm)

(Note that you should seek out the appropriate documentation & resources for your particular version of the OS.)

Comment: It's exactly the thing I searched. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think @dmc has the answer you're looking for.  In general, CL commands aren't available in C, but there are APIs available which do many of the same functions as CL commands.

If you actually want to run an operating system command, use system().

```
#include <stdlib.h>

   int main(void)
   {
     int result;

     result = system("CHGJOB INQMSGRPY(*DFT)");
```

Comment: Thanks, it's another interessant answer I will remember.